# ASP.Net chart control not applying the CSS class assigned to it

Tags: css, asp.net

I am trying to set the height and width of ASp.Net chart control using CSS. 
Although I add a CssClass attribute, it seems to be taking the height and width from bootstrap

```
 <div style="width:66%;position:relative;display:block;overflow:hidden;float:left;" id="divspcpchart">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">SP and CP of selected plant </asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <div style="width:80%;display:inline-block;margin:0 auto;">
                                        <asp:Chart ID="SPCPBarChart" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntDataSrcYearPerf"  CssClass="chartSPCP"  >   <%--Width="460px" Height="300px"--%>
                                            <BorderSkin BackColor="#E1E1E1" PageColor="#E1E1E1" SkinStyle="Emboss" />
                                            <Series>
                                                <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Year" YValueMembers="SP" ></asp:Series>
                                                <asp:Series Name="Series2" XValueMember="Year" YValueMembers="CP" ></asp:Series>
                                            </Series>
                                            <ChartAreas>
                                                    <asp:ChartArea Name="SPCPBarChartArea">
                                                            <AxisX Title="Year" TitleAlignment="Center" TextOrientation="Horizontal"></AxisX>
                                                            <AxisY Title="SP and CP" TitleAlignment="Center" TextOrientation="Rotated90"></AxisY>
                                                            <Area3DStyle Enable3D="false" />
                                                        </asp:ChartArea>
                                            </ChartAreas>
                                        </asp:Chart>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
```

If I set the height and width manually it shows up with the width of 406px.
My CSS class for the chart look like this

```
    #SPCPBarChart {
    width:460px;
    height:300px;
}
```

I have tried enclosing he chart control in div and setting the properties for the div, but it was still pulling the width from bootstrap.

Here is the browser debug capture

[image: Debug window screen capture]

Comment: browser will give first priority to inline styles. So from somewhere inline style is appending. you can add !important to your css style as shown below  #SPCPBarChart {
    width:460px !important;
    height:300px !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Added !important to the CSS class attributes. Thanks Vijay for reminding me about it.

```
#SPCPBarChart {
width:440px !important;
height:300px !important;
```

}